# Is there a better way to write the following method?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, datetime

Is there a better, more elegant solution to the following method?

Expected input format:

```
8 h 13 m
```

Expected output format:

```
8.13
```

My code:

```
private string FormatHours(string value)
{
    //Example: (Input = 10 h 53 m) (Output = 10.53) 
    var timeValues = Regex.Split(value, @"[\shm]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
    return ((timeValues != null) && (timeValues.Length == 2)) ? string.Format(@"{0:hh}.{1:mm}", timeValues[0], timeValues[1]) : null;
}
```

Comment: "I-want-to-send-an-email-how-can-I-do-that-using-LINQ" kind of question. Apparently LINQ has come to save the world...

Comment: Ok, LINQ has been removed from the title.  It looks like all I need is a little refinement in the regex, which will also remove the LINQ overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `Regex.Split` is overkill here. Regular old `Match` will give you exactly what you want:

```
private static string FormatHours(string value)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(value, @"^(?<hours>\d{1,2}) h (?<minutes>\d{1,2}) m$");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        int hours = int.Parse(m.Groups["hours"].Value);
        int minutes = int.Parse(m.Groups["minutes"].Value);
        if (hours >= 0 && hours < 24 && minutes >= 0 && minutes < 60)
            return string.Concat(hours, ".", minutes);
    }
    return null;   
}
```

Comment: You forgot `m` in the end of the pattern

Comment: Thanks, this works well. It also removes the LINQ overhead, excellent.

Comment: @abatischev: oops :) Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason not to use the following?

```
value.Replace(" h ",".").Replace(" m",string.Empty)
```

Comment: The only reason would be that it won't return `null` on unexpected input.

Comment: If that is required then you could both handle the null in calling code or throw a more meaningful exception and take your method further to check a valid number of hours and minutes (<60)

Comment: No, I said that it *won't* return `null`, it will just return an unchanged or partially changed string. The original code also does some degree of validation and returns `null` if it's not possible to parse the input. Besides, the original code will also handle input like "8h13m" and "8h 13m".

Comment: @Guffa I agree. I was describing changes to the original code.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could think of is that if `timeValues` was `null` calling `ToArray()` would throw

```
    private string FormatHours(string value)
    {
        var timeValues = Regex.Split(value, @"[\shm]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));

        if (timeValues == null || timeValues.Count() != 2)
            return null;

        string[] arr = timeValues.ToArray();
        return string.Format(@"{0:hh}.{1:mm}", arr[0], arr[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Expression:

```
^(\d{1,2}) h (\d{1,2}) m$
```

Code:

```
var input = "8 h 13 m";

var regex = new Regex(@"^(\d{1,2}) h (\d{1,2}) m$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
var match = regex.Match(input);
if (!match.Success) throw new Exception();
int h = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
int m = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);

var output = String.Format("{0}.{1}", h, m);

// or to be sure that that's the realistic numbers
var today = DateTime.Now;
var output2 = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, h, m, 0).ToString("hh.mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is not really suited for you problem. Using regular expressions in a slightly different manner than you are doing is what I would do:

```
String FormatHours(String value) {
  var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<hours>\d{1,2})\s*h\s*(?<minutes>\d{1,2})\s*m$");
  var match = regex.Match(value);
  if (match.Success) {
    var hours = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["hours"].Value);
    var minutes = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["minutes"].Value);
    if (hours < 24 && minutes < 60)
      return hours + "." + minutes;
  }
  return null;
}
```

You can adjust the regular expression to suit your exact needs. This one accepts strings like `10 h 53 m` and `10h53m`.

Comment: `\d{1,2}` is really better to exclude unrealistic numbers